# Printing a number with appropriate commas recursively

Tags: java, recursion

A sample input of 12345 should return 12,345. I have it figured out i think. Only problem is the string I get is reversed (543,21). Now i know there's ways to reverse a string pretty easily but that's more complexity to the running time so I was wondering if there was a straightforward way to do it within the auxiliary itself?

```
public void print(int n){
            String number = Integer.toString(n);
            StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
            if(number.length() > 3){ //Only worry about adding commas if its more than three digits
                printAux(number, answer, 1, number.length()-1);
                System.out.println(answer);
            }
        }

        private void printAux(String s, StringBuilder answer, int count, int index){
             if(index < 0){
                 return;
             }
             else{
                 //If the counter is at the 4th index meaning it has passed three digits
                 if(count%3 == 1 && count > 3){
                     answer.append(",");
                     index = index + 1;
                     count = 0;
                 }
                 else{
                     answer.append(s.charAt(index));
                 }
                 printAux(s, answer, count + 1, index - 1);
             }
        }
```

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to count up with `/` until you get zero, then count down from there.  I don't know if that will actually be less run time than reversing the characters in a short string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something simpler

```
public static void print(String s) {
        out.print(s.charAt(0));
        if (s.length() == 1) out.print("\n");
        else {
            if (((s.length()-1) % 3) == 0) out.print(",");
            print(s.substring(1));
        }
}
```

Explanation:

- always print the 1<sup>st</sup> character
- if there is no more character, print <kbd>CR</kbd>
- if there is at least one character to process, check if the length of what to process is a multiple of 3, if yes print a ","
- and call recursively *print* with the string minus the 1<sup>st</sup> character

Comment: Yes. Perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can can use `StringBuilder.reverse()` to reverse a `String` in one line like

```
String str = "abc";
str = new StringBuilder(str).reverse().toString();
```

But you could also use `printf`<sup>1</sup>. Something like,

```
public static void print(int n) {
    System.out.printf("%,d%n", n);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int num = 123456789;
    print(num);
}
```

Output is (as requested)

```
123,456,789
```

<sup>1<sub>See also [The Java Tutorials - Formatting Numeric Print Output](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html) for more options.</sub></sup>

Comment: That's cool, I didn't know that `printf` would do commas in decimals.  I think the OP actually needs to do it himself though (i.e., "recursively").  If not, then `DecimalFormat` is a pretty flexible class too.

Comment: Yeah. Helpful to see printf but it was meant to be a recursive implementation for test practice. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following `DecimalFormat` to get the job done.

```
String number = "1000500000.574";
double amount = Double.parseDouble(number);
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###.00");

System.out.println(formatter.format(amount));
```